# ng-bind-html inside input text does not bind

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Inside a `ng-repeat`, following code does not work:

```
<input type="text" ng-bind-html="row.value" />
```

Following does:

```
<span ng-bind-html="row.value"></span>
```

I guess `ng-bind-html` is unable to bind to a `input` element?

Also does `ng-bind-html` actually bind the element with the model (here `row.value`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `input` element cannot have innerHTML content. It uses `value` attribute instead to set the input value.

That's the same as you'd try to write.

```
<input type="text">
    your value
</input>
```

It will not work and that's not angular.js fault.

Comment: Thanks, does makes sense. I have achieved the same results with <input ng-model="row.value" > now.

Comment: I made same result by this... <input type="text" ng-model="name" value="John"> <input type="text" value = {{name}} >